# How to delete a resource lock in Azure using command line?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, rights, azure-resource-lock

I have created a lock of type CanNotDelete on a storage account in Azure. The lock works; I cannot delete the storage account as long as the lock exists. I can get the name and ID of the lock by doing this:

```
az lock list --resource-group "my-resource-group-name
```

Now I try to delete the lock from the command line like this:

```
az lock delete --resource-group "my-resource-group-name --name "name-of-my-lock"
```

This produces no output (no error message nor confirmation) and does nothing. The lock is still there.

If I add the `--debug` and `--verbose` flags to the delete command, I can see that the delete request returns HTTP 204. Still does nothing, though.

My user account has Owner rights. I can delete the lock via the Azure browser-based GUI (logged in as the same user). That works fine. But the command line does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the lock by specifying the lock id. For example, when I do

`az lock list --resource-group "my-resource-group-name"`

I get the following result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account-name>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/<lock-name>",
    "level": "CanNotDelete",
    "name": "<lock-name>",
    "notes": "",
    "owners": null,
    "resourceGroup": "<resource-group-name>",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks"
  }
]
```

I can then delete this lock using the following command:

```
az lock delete --ids "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account-name>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/<lock-name>"
```